# Where to add sitemap.xml in Laravel folder structure

Tags: php, laravel, seo, sitemap

Currently, I am using laravel 8, I have uploaded files on life. as per the laravel folder structure which is the correct place to laravel file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The public-facing folder for a Laravel project is 'public'. Placing the file within 'public' should making it publicly accessible.